# How may I address a particular cell of a DataGridView row in a compiler-checked fashion?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

For example like this:

```
myDataGridView.Rows[0].<something>myColumnName</something>.
```

Currently I am using

```
myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["myColumnName"]
```

but this is not compiler-checked.

[deleted]

Thanks.

Comment: I am not very on the fashion, could you please explain what a *compiler-checked fashion* means?

Comment: @ChrisJJ could you show how you have `myColumnName` as a Type

Comment: @Darin, a fashion that is checked by the compiler, e.g. causes a compiler error of the column does not exist. The current solution causes an error only at run-time.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, but you create columns at runtime, don't you?

Comment: @msarchet, I have myColumnName as a type created by the Designer in Form1.Designer.cs. I have added an exampoe added to the question.

Comment: @Darin, no, DataGridView columns may be created at design time and I expect compile-time checking to be possible only for those that are.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, it's a false impression what you call design-time. Behind the scenes Visual Studio generates code for you when you define columns in a grid. This code of course evaluates only at runtime. So talking about a compile time safety in a DataGridView hardly makes any sense. Not to mention that this control was created back in the dark ages of .NET 1.1 when things like generics didn't exist. So I guess you are pretty out of luck here.

Comment: @Darin, I accept that part of the code evaluated only at run time but the column type name is available at compile time. But if you're saying that's insufficient, OK - thanks.

Comment: @Darin, my mistake: the column type name is no use here. It is the column member that is of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[RevParticlesID.Index]
```

for:

```
myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["myColumnName"]
```

Comment: Two caveats: 1) RevParticlesID must have been assigned a column, else .Name fails 2) If this code is outside the Form class, the Designer's "private" on RevParticlesID must be changed to "public", inc. after the Designer changes it back upon an edit to the DataGridView control.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have the compiler ensure you're using actual column names. But you can get close using `const`s or an `enum`.

```
struct ColumnNames
{
    public const string myFirstColumn = "myFirstColumn";
    public const string mySecondColumn = "mySecondColumn";
    public const string myOtherColumn = "myOtherColumn";
}

myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[ColumnNames.myFirstColumn]
```

or

```
enum ColumnNames
{
    myFirstColumn,
    mySecondColumn,  
    myOtherColumn
}

myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[ColumnNames.myFirstColumn.ToString()]
```

But it's up to you to make sure you use the `ColumnNames` values as column names.